# PHP foreach invalid value

Tags: php, post, foreach

I have several like this in my HTML code:

```
<input class="table" type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="finger food" />
```

and this in my PHP code:

```
$checkboxes = stripslashes($_POST['interest']);

//process the checkboxes
foreach ($checkboxes as $value) {
    $selectedChkbx .= $value . ", ";
}
```

I am getting:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()foreach()

and my `$selectedChkbx` variable isn't getting any values inside of it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: a friend recommended it, I honestly thought it wouldn't work and now I realize I was right...

Comment: He probably has http://www.php.net/magic_quotes turned on.

Comment: May I ask where this $selectedChkbx variable would go? I hope it's email body.

Comment: @premiso I doubt so. I even doubt that these values contains any special symbols that being escaped.  Anyway it should be completely different approach, not such a local one.

Comment: @Col. Sharpnel, yes it's email body

Comment: You should be checking `get_magic_quotes_gpc` and stripping slashes only if magic quotes are enabled. Ideally you'd do this earlier in your program's execution, hiding it from the files containing your business/controller logic.

Comment: All the concatenation-based solutions, including the one you've accepted, will have a trailing comma after the last value.  You should be using `implode` for this kind of thing, that's what it's for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

stripslashes($_POST['interest']);

stripslashes doesn't work on arrays!

Do it like this:

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['interest'];

//process the checkboxes
foreach ($checkboxes as $value) {
    $selectedChkbx .= stripslashes($value) . ", ";
}
```

Answer to your comment:

```
$array = array('zero', array('one', array('two', 'three', 'four'), 'five'), 'six', 'seven', array('eight'));

echo r_implode(", ", stripslashes_deep($array));

# code from http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}


# code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
function r_implode( $glue, $pieces )
{
  foreach( $pieces as $r_pieces )
  {
    if( is_array( $r_pieces ) )
    {
      $retVal[] = r_implode( $glue, $r_pieces );
    }
    else
    {
      $retVal[] = $r_pieces;
    }
  }
  return implode( $glue, $retVal );
}
```

This gives you:

```
zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight
```

**Edit**
Replaced personal recursive function with a more elegant one ;)

Comment: what if the array is nested into multiple levels and $value is again an array?

Comment: useful or not, it solves the problem he's having. I've replaced my own code with a more elegant one ;)

Comment: it solves the problem wrong way. but if your only concern is reputation points, it explains

Comment: actually it solves kali's proplem, not the opening poster's one. And I bet he hasn't such a problem in real, but just for chatter. You did your job in vain, dude

Answer (score 3):

[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) is probably turning the array into a string. That means `$checkboxes` is a string and you cannot use a string in `foreach`.

Either apply `stripslashes` on each value of the array inside `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST['interest'] as $value) {
    $selectedChkbx .= stripslashes($value) . ", ";
}
```

Or use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply a function on each value of an array:

```
$checkboxes = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST['interest']);
```

Then you can join the values with [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$selectedChkbx = implode(',', $checkboxes);
```

And if your `stripslashes` code is to revert the effects of [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes), better try to [disable them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Comment: That's perfect explanation which I often lack of :)

Answer (score 2):

just get rid of this useless stripslashes function

I'd make it with just one line:

```
$selectedChkbx = implode(", ",$_POST['interest']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this: `$checkboxes = stripslashes($_POST['interest']);`

The stripslashes function will convert the array $_POST['interest'] into an empty string.

Instead you should just:

```
foreach ($_POST['interest'] as $value) {
    $selectedChkbx .= stripslashes($value) . ", ";
}
```

Also, magic quotes are deprecated. It is recommend you to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You convert it to a string using this:

```
$checkboxes = stripslashes($_POST['interest']);
```

My bet is it assigns the value called "Array" as the string. If you want to remove slashes from the entire array use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/array_filter). But it would be wiser to just disable [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes) on the server so you do not have to `strip_slashes`.

```
$checkboxes = array_filter($_POST['interest'], 'stripslashes');
```

I would highly suggestion you look into the magic quotes issue and fix the problem at the core.

Answer (score 0):

[Stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) will cast the return value to string. Still people answering here does not have the luxury to "dude just get rid of stripslashes" or "go disable magic quotes!!"

if you or your friend needs to stripslashes and for some reason using magic quotes on (may be a shared host) than you should wrap stripslashes function for arrays.

for example something like:

```
function myStripper($value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $newValue) {
            return myStripper($newValue);
        }
    } else {
        return stripslashes($value);
    }
}

$checkboxes = myStripper($_POST['interest']);

//process the checkboxes
foreach ($checkboxes as $value) {
    $selectedChkbx .= $value . ", ";
}
```

should do the trick and recursively strip your variables.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php